# Absolute value problem involving linear programming

Tags: inequality, linear-programming

John R. has up to $10,000 to invest. His wife suggests investing in two bonds, A and B. Bond A is rather risky with an annual yield of 10%, and bond B is more conservative with a yield of 7%. He decides to invest at most 6,000 dollars in bond A, at least 2,000 dollars in bond B, and to invest at least as much in bond A as in bond B. How should he invest up to 10,000 dollars in order to maximize his annual yield?

---

Let xa = the number of dollars invested in bond A
Let xb= the number of dollars invested in bond B

The annual yield is Y = .10xa + .07xa
We want to maximize Y, but there are some constraints on xa and xb.
We must assume money must be non negative.      xa ≥ 0 and xb ≥ 0
We must invest at least as much in bond A as in bond B.  xa ≥ xb

The link below is the problem that I found online with more information, exact same problem but no solution.(page 3, example 20.2)

http://seu1.org/files/level4/MATH-251/Linear_Programming/Linear_Programming_1.pdf

Comment: Please do not delete a question once you get an answer.  This is disrespectful to the answerer who took the time to respond to you, and to future askers who might find your Q&A useful.

Answer (score 0):

As the examples show, you can plot the feasible region in two dimensions, find the extreme points, evaluate the objective function at each extreme point, and keep the best one (that maximizes yield).  The extreme points turn out to be:
\begin{align}
(2000,2000), (5000,5000), (6000,2000), (6000,4000)
\end{align}
Now which one is the best?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do that at all, what exactly do I plot and how ? I don't know how to do any of this because i do not know even the basics of linear programming, unfortunately the instructor gave us this problem in advanced algebra course...oh wait you just edited the post, let me see... (6000,4000) would maximize this ? (6000+4000=10000) Would that be correct ?

Comment: Yes, $(6000,4000)$ maximizes the yield (\$880), and it is sort of an intuitive answer, even without writing down any inequalities.  Because both investments have positive yield, you want to invest all the money.  Because investment A has the higher return, invest as much as you can (\$6000) there, leaving \$4000 to invest in B.  Now notice that you have invested at least $2000 in B and at least as much in A as in B, so those constraints are satisfied, too.

Comment: Oh I see, I am beginning to understand it but if I would write inequalities for this problem then how could I do it ?

Comment: The inequalities are in the pdf you linked.  You would then plot the feasible region as shown in those examples.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you!